# ArrayList null not empty

Tags: java, arraylist, null, is-empty

If the input ArrayList is empty or the ArrayList is null then the method should return null.

I am having trouble finding a working solution for the part where the arrayList is null.

I am checking whether the arrayList is empty but i don't know how to check if the arrayList is null.

I get the nullPointerExceptino error and an error saying that my return null statement when checking if the arraylist is wrong is dead code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Excerice_1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Float> PA = new ArrayList<Float>();
    
        PA.add(null);

        
        
        System.out.println(PrefixAverage(PA));
        
    }

    public static ArrayList<Float> PrefixAverage(ArrayList<Float> X) {
        float sum = 0;
        
        ArrayList<Float> PrefixAverages = new ArrayList<Float>();
        
        if (X.isEmpty() )
            
            return null;
        else if (X == null)
            return null;
                
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < X.size(); i++) {
                sum += X.get(i);
                PrefixAverages.add(sum / (i+1));
                
            }

        return PrefixAverages;
        }
        
            
    }

}
```

Comment: Check for null _before_ checking for empty.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, Your code should handle null values before checking empty condition for List. I have combined both condtions here but sequence here matters.
i.e. `null == X || X.isEmpty()`

Secondly when doing summation you should check if item in the list is null and then add 0  if it is null or your actual value

```
sum += null != X.get(i) ? X.get(i) : 0;
```

Working solution would be:

```
public class Excerice_1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Float> PA = new ArrayList<Float>();

        PA.add(null);



        System.out.println(PrefixAverage(PA));

    }

    public static ArrayList<Float> PrefixAverage(ArrayList<Float> X) {
        float sum = 0;

        ArrayList<Float> PrefixAverages = new ArrayList<Float>();

        if (null == X || X.isEmpty())
            return null;
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < X.size(); i++) {
                sum += null != X.get(i) ? X.get(i) : 0;
                PrefixAverages.add(sum / (i+1));

            }

            return PrefixAverages;
        }


    }
}
```